# How to set custom field name ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use a collection_select for state just to filter cities, but I don't want to save the state_id in db. My "college" model has only city and college field. That's why it's throwing while instantiating :state_id I believe, I am new to rails. I am not able to figure it out. :(

```
<%= form_for @college do |f| %>

<div class="form-group">

<%= f.label "Select city"%>
<%= f.collection_select(:state_id, State.all, :id, :state,  {},  {class: "form-control"})%>
    </div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :city_id, "Select city"%>
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :city,  {},  {class: "form-control"})%>
</div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :college, "college Name"%>
<%= f.text_field :college, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter city name", required: true%>
<br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>

</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try putting `attr_accessor :state_id` in `college` model.

Comment: Thanks @Pavan It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just define state_id  attribute accessor in your `college.rb` model :

```
attr_accessor :state_id
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your model you should define state_id as attr_accessor like :-

```
   class College

      attr_accessor :state_id

end
```